# Remove (or replace) all hyperlinks from an RSS feed? (probably with yahoo pipes)

Tags: regex, rss, edit, yahoo-pipes

ive seen some yahoo pipes that would, e.g., allow to extract a feed from twitter, remove the hyperlink (so just the anchor text will stay) or edit another URL into it automatically.

The question is: How can this be done with any feed (removing all clickable links while leaving the rest unchanged), not just with twitter?

Thanks,

tellio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: http://img248.imageshack.us/img248/8501/pipeexample.jpg]
We need 2 modules. `Fetch Feed` and `Regex`. You can find them from left panel. Drag them to right area. Hook them as I did. In `Fetch Feed` module put your RSS that will be formatted by Pipe. In `Regex` module `-` choose `Item link`. `replace` will be `.*`. Leave `with` empty. At last save it.

Comment: Sorry, I understood your question wrong. I will take a snapshot of a pipe that used twitter rss.

Comment: @Tellio Your welcome. Don't forget to check mark. This way the other people can understand that this answer is true.