# Yahoo Pipes - RSS without hyperlinks?

Tags: html, regex, rss, hyperlink, yahoo-pipes

I found this topic: [Remove (or replace) all hyperlinks from an RSS feed? (probably with yahoo pipes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856535/remove-or-replace-all-hyperlinks-from-an-rss-feed-probably-with-yahoo-pipes)

So, the idea is, while the RSS feed remains intact, hyperlinks would be removed.

but it simply doesn't seem to work under any circumstances.
(I tried already tested and working pipes with this module as well, didn't pull any content either).

Any idea how to get this running?

Thanks,

T.T.

Answer (score 0):

The link you provided to the other SO question seems to be talking about removing the rss item links. If you want to remove links from the rss description that would be a different matter. You will need to write some regex that looks for the  and  tags.